# How can I get data from table using parent()

Tags: node.js, meteor, html-table

I try to get data from table, there is a link "Kaydet" when I click it, I must get a data from table which belong to it row, I share my table, it is like below:
https://hizliresim.com/PB3Dmv

> sozlesme.js

```
Template.sozlesmeListele.events({
    'click .kaydet': function (event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var sozlesmeBilgileriAl = $(event.currentTarget).parent().parent().find(".secilenArac");
        saveSozlesmeBilgisi = sozlesmeBilgileriAl.val();
        alert(saveSozlesmeBilgisi);
    }
});
```

> sozlesmeAl.html

```
<tbody>
    {{#each sozlesmeList}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{kullaniciadi}}</td>
        <td>{{rezervasyonnumarasi}}</td>
        <td>{{KiradaKalicakGun}}</td>
        <td>{{telefon}}</td>
        <td>{{alistarihi}}</td>
        <td>{{iadetarihi}}</td>
        <td class="secilenArac">{{secilenarac}}</td>
        <td>{{aracteslimadresi}}</td>
        <td>{{odenecekTutar}} TL.</td>
        <td>Ceyhun TEKİN</td>
        <td> <a href="javascript:;" class="kaydet">Kaydet</a></td>


    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Deciphering Turkish Javascript is a new challenge for me but if I'm reading your question correctly, you want to figure out which row was clicked and get the data from that row, correct?

The simplest solution is to break up your template into an outer list-level one and an inner, row-level one. Then you can react to click events on the row and get your data context automatically. No need to try to figure out which row was clicked on.

```
Template.tekSozlesme.events({
  'click .kaydet': function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
      console.log(this); <!-- *this* will be the row data context
      ... do something with it
  }
});

<template name="sozlesmeListele">
  <tbody>
    {{#each sozlesmeList}}
      {{> tekSozlesme }}
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</template>

<template name="tekSozlesme">
  <tr>
    <td>{{kullaniciadi}}</td>
    <td>{{rezervasyonnumarasi}}</td>
    <td>{{KiradaKalicakGun}}</td>
    <td>{{telefon}}</td>
    <td>{{alistarihi}}</td>
    <td>{{iadetarihi}}</td>
    <td class="secilenArac">{{secilenarac}}</td>
    <td>{{aracteslimadresi}}</td>
    <td>{{odenecekTutar}} TL.</td>
    <td>Ceyhun TEKİN</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="kaydet">Kaydet</a></td>
  </tr>
</template>
```